# I am getting extra column while converting multiple excel '.xlsx' to '.csv' files in python?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas, csv

i am trying to convert multiple excel file '.xlsx' to '.csv' using pandas in python. i am able to convert multiple excel file in csv but i am getting an extra column at the beginning of '.csv' file.

here is my code-

```
import pandas as pd,xlrd,glob

excel_files = glob.glob(r"C:\Users\Videos\file reader\*.xlsx")
for excel_file in excel_files:

  print("Converting '{}'".format(excel_file))
  try:
      df = pd.read_excel(excel_file)
      output = excel_file.split('.')[0]+'.csv'
      df.to_csv(output)
  except KeyError:
      print("  Failed to convert")
```

input-

[image]

output-

[image]

As we can see in output file there is an extra column. can anyone show me 
how can i remove it ?

Thanks

Comment: i think you are looking for index=False.   https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

set `df.to_csv(output,index=False)`

full code:

```
import pandas as pd,xlrd,glob

excel_files = glob.glob(r"C:\Users\Videos\file reader\*.xlsx")
for excel_file in excel_files:

  print("Converting '{}'".format(excel_file))
  try:
      df = pd.read_excel(excel_file)
      output = excel_file.split('.')[0]+'.csv'
      df.to_csv(output,index=False)
  except KeyError:
      print("  Failed to convert")
```